# AngularJS: Ensure that all Controllers are loaded before broadcasting/emitting events

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket

I'm developing an AngularJS application and ran into (maybe) a quite basic problem. Multiple controllers are involved which talk to each other via $broadcast and $on. The Application is using websockets and should start to do it's things after the websocket has been opened. So now the question remains, who should open the websocket because all controllers have to be loaded at the time to listen for broadcasts.

So there is a service responsible for handling the websocket which does the following:

```
this.websocket = new WebSocket(webSocketUrl()); 
  this.websocket.onopen = function() { 
    $timeout(function() { 
      $rootScope.$broadcast("websocket_opened"); 
    }); 
};
```

Now the 'main' controller of the application reacts to this broadcast and sends out a few request.

```
$scope.$on("websocket_opened", function() { 
  // some requests 
});
```

Soon after the answer from the server will be in and the aforementioned websocket service will broadcast the arrival of a packet.

```
this.websocket.onmessage = function(data) { 
  $rootScope.$broadcast("packet received", data); 
};
```

The problem is, the answers to those requests often reach the client before the 'sub-controllers' have been loaded by AngularJS and so they 'miss' the broadcasts and therefore the data.

Is there a way to ensure that all controllers have been loaded and are therefore listening to broadcasts? Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?